# Append to end of each line with sed on Windows?

Tags: windows, unix, sed

I am using `sed` on Windows (the GNU port).

I execute:

```
$> sed "s/$/./" < /data.txt
```

And get:

```
.ne
.wo
.hree
```

But expect.

```
one.
two.
three.
```

The following works though I don't think it should.  The way I read it is "replace the last character of the line with a period."   I'm afraid it won't work consistently when used elsewhere.  The intent isn't to replace the last character with a period but to append a period.

```
$> sed "s/.$/./" < /data.txt
```

I am not sure if the file encoding or something specific to windows is causing the issues I'm having or if it's just lack of experience with `sed`.  Ideas?

Comment: Try `sed -n "l;s/$/./;l" < /data.txt` to see the data as sed sees it before and after the substitution command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hexdump -C` sheds some light:

```
$ sed 's/$/./' < t.dos | hexdump -C
00000000  6f 6e 65 0d 2e 0a 74 77  6f 0d 2e 0a 74 68 72 65  |one...two...thre|
00000010  65 0d 2e 0a                                       |e...|
00000014
```

There, `2e` is the dot, the `0d` before it is carriage return aka `\r`, and after that is the newline aka `\n`. In other words, `sed` treats `\r` as the end of the line instead of `\r\n` together, and thus `\r` is still part of the line, so it puts the dot after it, then adds back the newline as usual.

I think this does what you want, but it's not exactly pretty:

```
$ sed 's/.$/.\r/' < t.dos | hexdump -C
00000000  6f 6e 65 2e 0d 0a 74 77  6f 2e 0d 0a 74 68 72 65  |one...two...thre|
00000010  65 2e 0d 0a                                       |e...|
00000014
```

The above is not so good, because it will only work if the input is in dos format, otherwise it will break the file. A better solution might be to first strip any `\r` and add them back manually later, like this:

```
$ tr -d '\r' < t.dos | sed -e 's/$/.\r/' | hexdump -C
00000000  6f 6e 65 2e 0d 0a 74 77  6f 2e 0d 0a 74 68 72 65  |one...two...thre|
00000010  65 2e 0d 0a                                       |e...|
00000014
```

Comment: I found that by adding the `--text` option to `sed` I could get the result I wanted but I was unaware of `hexdump` and I can see how that'd be useful.  Thanks!